# Reading XML file faster in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, .net-2.0, xmltextreader

I have multiple XML files that I need to parse.  Problem is that I only need some data in the last couple of lines.

I currently use XMLTextReader and reader.ReadToFollowing("DATANEEDED"); but it is still too slow.  Does anyone know if I can 'tail' an XML file and read from there?  (taking into account the tail would not be a valid XML file) or any other ways to retrieve the last few nodes in the XML without parsing through the entire XML file?

I am using .NET 2.0 so no in-built linq :(

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps see the `(Stream, XmlNodeType, XmlParserContext)` overloaded constructor... you may still have to initially position the stream on a valid element -- I do not know -- but that should move you as fast as you can move the stream :-)

Answer (score -1):

`XmlDocument` is a better choice. Within it use xPath queries. I guess `XmlDocument` take cares about performance automatically.

Comment: You guess wrong. using XMLDocument will be orders of magnitude slower than XMLTextReader, especially for large files.

Comment: That's what I read too.  XMLTextReader seems to be the fastest.

Comment: XmlDocument is a lot slower, see for example http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html